# How to practice managing (submitting changes, accepting changes, etc.) a repo?

Tags: git, github, open-source, git-rebase, git-fork

**Short and sweet:** How can I practice forking a GitHub repo, making changes to *both* the forked and original repo, submitting a pull request, merging the changes, rebasing, etc.?

**More details:** The difficulty is that you cannot fork your own repo on GitHub. So (it seems?) you cannot submit a pull request to a repo that you also have the ability to accept and merge changes to. But maybe there is a way around this?

This is mainly for pedagogical purposes. I am all of a sudden finding myself in a situation where I am managing an OSS project with multiple contributors, and I want to get some practice at these things before mucking with live code that people depend on.

**Clarification:** I am not asking how to fork, how to rebase, submit a pull request, etc.---I am wondering if it is possible to simulate / create a sanitized environment in which I can simultaneously play the role of maintainer (original repo) and contributor (forked repo).

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate account and use one as the maintainer and one as the contributer

Comment: How do you manage multiple accounts at the command line? Surely this is possible but I've not seen this done before.

Comment: you can google around for more guides, but basically something like this: http://hmkcode.com/git-tutorial/how-to-deal-with-multiple-github-accounts-on-one-computer/

Comment: Multiple accounts is easiest if you use SSH to authenticate to github and setup a ~/.ssh/config file.